# Why are some properties are duplicated in JavaFX Scene Builder?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Some properties are duplicated and have different values simultaneously in Scene Builder?

What does this mean?

Here, grid pane row is selected:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicated"? It's not clear what you're asking. Which values specifically are you talking about?

Comment: For example `Pref Height` is duplicated and has the value of 170 in one case and the value of 503 in the other.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm not familiar with JavaFX, but this looks to be bad labeling on the UI; I think the first one is for the grid's first row, while the second one is for the entire pane.

Comment: If select entire pane, figures are different again and don't coincide with anyones from here.

Comment: Ah no, probably you are right